# KeyboardView key colour is not setting properly in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-custom-keyboard

I ma trying to change the keyboardview key color in Android. Key color is changed. But text is not visible in the key.

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
            if (key.codes[0] == 53) {
                Drawable dr = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.samplekeybackground);
                dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
                dr.draw(canvas);

            }
        }

    }
```

***samplekeybackground.xml:***

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
    <!-- Pressed state -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /></selector>
```

***normal.xml***

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#AABBCC" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
```

***pressed.xml***

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#000000" />
        <solid android:color="#CCBBAA"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
```

[image: OP image]

Please let me some ideas to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set the bg color programmatically then we need to set the text programmatically.

```
private void drawText(Canvas canvas, Keyboard.Key key) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);


        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (key.label != null) {
            String label = key.label.toString();

            Field field;

            if (label.length() > 1 && key.codes.length < 2) {
                int labelTextSize = 0;
                try {
                    field = KeyboardView.class.getDeclaredField("mLabelTextSize");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    labelTextSize = spToPx((int) field.get(this));
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                paint.setTextSize(labelTextSize);
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            } else {
                int keyTextSize = 0;
                try {
                    field = KeyboardView.class.getDeclaredField("mLabelTextSize");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    keyTextSize = spToPx((int) field.get(this));
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                paint.setTextSize(keyTextSize);
                paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            }

            paint.getTextBounds(key.label.toString(), 0, key.label.toString()
                    .length(), bounds);
            canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width / 2),
                    (key.y + key.height / 2) + bounds.height() / 2, paint);
        } else if (key.icon != null) {
            key.icon.setBounds(key.x + (key.width - key.icon.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2, key.y + (key.height - key.icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2,
                    key.x + (key.width - key.icon.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2 + key.icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), key.y + (key.height - key.icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2 + key.icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
            key.icon.draw(canvas);
        }

    }
```